# Autogenerate OpenAPI documentation with Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, swagger, openapi

is it possible to auto-generate OpenAPI documentation with Azure Functions e.g. like how it's possible with the SwaggerGen when using Swashbuckle with ASP .NET Core? The documentation should contain the different endpoints with their possible input and response models and StatusCodes. It would be awesome if I could view the docs in a web ui.

At the moment, I found two possible packages:

1. A Swashbuckle Adaption for Azure Functions: https://github.com/vitalybibikov/AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle
2. An official OpenAPI Extension from Microsoft: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension

With the first one, it's only possible to detect my models/DTOs and the different endpoints.
But the relation between endpoints and models and the possible response codes have to be manually set by attributes on the several functions.

For the second one, there is no auto-detection at all. Everything only works with attributes. Additionally the package is still in preview.

Comment: "possible response codes have to be manually set by attributes on the several functions." Isnt this true for services as well

Answer (score 1):

As per the microsoft official [doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension), which is not in preview now, You can enable OpenAPI Endpoints on Azure Functions by using

[In-Process Model](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/enable-open-api-endpoints-in-proc.md)
and
[Out-of-Process Model](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/enable-open-api-endpoints-out-of-proc.md) only.

By using the extensions as mentioned in the document we can generate OpenAPI Document.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer (it's just links, which isn't really an answer).